# mysql_fetch error in my cron script sourcebans.php

Tags: mysql, fetch

i hope someone can help me.

**If i use my script, i get this error:**

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
..../includes/cron/sourcebans/sourcebans.php on line 171
```

**Here is the Code from this line:**

```
// ########################################################################
// ######################### START MAIN SCRIPT ############################
// ########################################################################
$res = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT `username`, `user`.`userid` as userid,
`usergroupid`, `membergroupids`, `email`, `".$steamid_custom_field."` FROM ".
TABLE_PREFIX ."user LEFT JOIN `". TABLE_PREFIX ."userfield` ON 
user`.`userid`=`userfield`.`userid`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
```

I don´t know, what the problem and i hope someone can help me to resolve it.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I don´t know, what to do... here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/PzQcd8Yt

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: You're using vbulletin's API to call the query (`$vbulletin->db->query_read`), so why don't you use the same API to get the results. Maybe vbulletin doesn't use `mysql_query()` internally, in which case `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the call to `query_read` failed, and so `$res` is null.  You need to figure out what went wrong in `query_read`, but I'm not familiar with the architecture you're using so I can't tell you how to find error messages.